# Google Cloud Spanner real time Change Data Capture to PubSub/Kafka through Cloud Data Fusion or Others

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-spanner, google-cloud-data-fusion, change-data-capture

I would like to achieve a real time change data capture (log-based preferred) pipeline from Google Cloud Spanner to PubSub/Kafka for my downstream real time applications. Could you please let me know if there is a great and cost-effective way to achieve that? I will appreciate any advice and recommendations.

In addition, for Cloud Data Fusion from google, I noticed that it could achieve real time from mysql/postgresql to cloud spanner, but I did not find the way go from cloud spanner to pubsub/kafka in real time.

Also, I found another two ways, which to be listed here for any comments or suggestions.

1. Use Debezium, a log-based change data capture Kafka connector from the link https://cloud.google.com/architecture/capturing-change-logs-with-debezium#deploying_debezium_on_gke_on_google_cloud
2. Create a polling service (which may miss some data) to poll data from cloud spanner from the link: https://cloud.google.com/architecture/deploying-event-sourced-systems-with-cloud-spanner

If you have any suggestion or comment on this, I will be really grateful.

Comment: To clarify, the first method has a misleading name, and it actually uses the JDBC connector. Currently, cloud spanner does not has a log-mining interface, so it does not support any log-based method now.

Answer (score 1):

There's a open source implementation of a polling service for Cloud Spanner that can also automatically push changes to PubSub here: https://github.com/cloudspannerecosystem/spanner-change-watcher

It is however **not log-based**. It has some inherent limitations:

- It can miss updates if the same record is updated twice within the polling interval. In that case, only the last value will be reported.
- It only supports soft deletes.

You could have a look at the samples to see if it is something that might suit your needs at least to some degree: https://github.com/cloudspannerecosystem/spanner-change-watcher/tree/master/samples

Comment: Thank you so much for your resources! I will take a look at them.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Spanner has a new feature called [Change Streams](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/change-streams) that would allow building a downstream pipeline from Spanner to PubSub/Kafka.

At this time, there's not a pre-packaged Spanner to PubSub/Kafka connector.

The way to [read change streams](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/change-streams#reading_change_streams) currently is to use the SpannerIO Apache Beam connector that would allow building the pipeline with Dataflow, or also directly querying the API.

Disclaimer: I'm a Developer Advocate that works with the Cloud Spanner team.

Answer (score 0):

To close the loop here, Kafka and Pub/Sub support has been added for Spanner change streams:

Spanner change streams to Pub/Sub Dataflow template:
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided/cloud-spanner-change-streams-to-pubsub

Debezium based Kafka connector to stream changes into topic partitions:
https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/change-streams/use-kafka
https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/spanner.html